# Chrome extension add button to site

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do the simplest thing ever and this won't work. I'm literally trying to add a button to every tweet, for now, which will later capture it and send it offiste when clicked. This is what I have and it won't work, it's like I'm failing hello world.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Tweep",
  "author": "Fisher",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1",
  "icons": { "16": "logo.png",
           "48": "logo.png",
          "128": "logo.png" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["jquery.js", "addbutton.js"],
      "matches": ["https://twitter.com/*"]

    }
  ]
}
```

addbutton.js

```
$( ".ProfileTweet-actionList u-cf js-actions" ).append( "<p>test</p>" );
```

Here's the funny part. Chrome will output two errors when I load the extension

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)append...
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

It will throw these errors pretty much whatever I write, however, if I add `alert("boom");` to the addbutton.js, it will execute.

Comment: Try opening the console in a web browser with this file loaded on it and type 'jquery' into the console and press enter. If you receive back the jQuery object, it is loaded. If not, this may be why you are getting `$ is not defined`. If that is the case, ensure jQuery is loaded onto your page PRIOR to this file, and that should resolve the `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the jQuery library. Obviously it is not loaded.

In case you do, then make sure you include it before the use of any jQuery object.

It might be that you are using other libraries that interfere, can you check and edit your question please?

Comment: Yeah, I re-downloaded the jQuery and re-wrote all the files. I'm not getting the error anymore, however, now it just doesn't work, doesn't add the `<p>test</p>` where it's supposed to add it